# PowerShell New-ADUser fails in cycle

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Here is my powershell code for adding test user accounts to Active directory... Problem: when `$i` is between 1 and 99, everything works fine... immediatelly after `$i` reaches 100, created accounts are disabled and error message in console telling "`The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain.`"

Any idea what's the problem?

//EDIT: no password policy is set for the domain

Thanks

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

for($i=1; $i -le 500; $i++){

$name="Name1_$i" #name
$surname="Surname1_$i" #surname
$logon="logon1$i" #logon
$plainPass='pAs5w0rd'+$i+'&G'
$password=ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $plainPass 


New-ADUser -Enabled 1 -Name $name -AccountPassword $password -DisplayName "$name $surname" -GivenName $name -UserPrincipalName $logon@testdomain.local -SamAccountName $logon -Surname $surname -Path "OU=SomeTest,DC=testdomain,DC=local"

}
```

Comment: No password policy but the default password policy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I reproduce your problem, you are under the default domain policy. And when :

```
name = Name1_100
surname = Surname1_100
samAccountName = Logon1100
```

A too big part of the name is in the password (see default passord policy on the domain called [password complexity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

The samAccountName is checked in its entirety only to determine whether it is part of the password

So try

```
$plainPass='pAs5w0rd'+($i+1)+'&G'
```

It will work.